# Does using an Intel register for its "intended purpose" increase efficiency?

Tags: assembly, intel

[This article](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html) claims that each register has an intended purpose and more importantly,

> When the engineers at Intel designed
>   the original 8086 processor, they had
>   a special purpose in mind for each
>   register. As they designed the
>   instruction set, they created many
>   optimizations and special instructions
>   based on the function they expected
>   each register to perform. Using
>   registers according to Intel's
>   original plan allows the code to take
>   full advantage of these optimizations.
>   Unfortunately, this seems to be a lost
>   art. Few coders are aware of Intel's
>   overall design, and most compilers are
>   too the simplistic or focused on
>   execution speed to use the registers
>   properly. Understanding how the
>   registers and instruction set fit
>   together, however, is an important
>   step on the road to effortless
>   size-coding.

Are there any other sources to corroborate this article? If so, I'd really like to check it out.

Please note I'm not talking about situations where fast operations like `STOS` uses `edi` - I'm just wondering if there is any performance degradation if I use `eax` and `esi` as counters instead of `ecx` or is it just about readability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really anymore -- or at least not very often anyway. Using ECX as a counter lets you use the LOOP instruction. At one time, that was a significant advantage, but on most recent CPUs, a LOOP takes longer to execute than the combination of DEC ECX/JNZ wherever. The possible advantage is that it reduces memory bandwidth usage, which is a bottleneck more and more often. It can also be an advantage when/if you can use the other forms like LOOPNZ, which can be relatively complex to simulate with separate instructions.

Answer (score 5):

There are instructions in the instruction set which use specific registers, which are smaller (and often faster) than the equivalent functions which target any register.

Comment: Most notably references to AX vs. others.