# Is the EAX register optimized for calculations on modern processors?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

The article [The Art of picking Intel Registers](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html) reads:

> [Because] most calculations occur in the accumulator, the x86 architecture contains many optimized instructions for moving data in and out of this register. To start, the processor has sixteen byte-sized XCHG opcodes for swapping data between the accumulator and any other register. These aren't terribly useful, but they show how strongly the Intel engineers preferred the accumulator over the other registers. For them, it was better to swap data into the accumulator to than to work with it where it was. Other instructions that move data in and out of the accumulator are LODS, STOS, IN, OUT, INS, OUTS, SCAS, and XLAT. Finally, the MOV instruction has a special one-byte opcode for moving data into the accumulator from a constant memory location.
>
> In your code, try to perform as much work in the accumulator as possible.

As the the article is dated 2003 I'm curious to know if this is true modern processors (hello from 2017). Points given for references to Intel documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does using an Intel register for its "intended purpose" increase efficiency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903047/does-using-an-intel-register-for-its-intended-purpose-increase-efficiency)

Comment: Thanks. A reference to the docs will still be nice tho'.

Comment: Yes, it is a strange situation we have here: this question is kind of a duplicate of that one, but that one received very poor answers, so let's see if this one fares any better.

Comment: AX was never "optimized for calculations", it was always just the ISA that favours AX with special encodings and by making it an implicit operand and so on.

Comment: The 8088 in the original PC had an 8-bit data bus. Being able to use a single byte opcode was a significant advantage.

Comment: There have been absolutely no changes from what is stated in that article. You can verify this by looking at any documentation for the x86 ISA that lists the available instructions and their encodings. That's all that they are saying there: there are shorter encodings for certain instructions that use the accumulator register, and there are certain instructions that can only (implicitly) use the accumulator register. There is otherwise absolutely no speed advantage to using it, and there never was, in 2003 nor in 1981. (Although the size advantage was very important in 81, as Bo already said.)

Answer (score 3):

Modern Intel processors use a technique called *register renaming.* In a nutshell, the CPU has a bunch of registers (~100) that are disconnected from the registers you see in your assembly. The CPU manages that pool of registers and maps them to register names as needed. Thus, all general purpose registers are indistinguishable as far as the CPU is concerned.

When programming assembly from hand, register choice can be important as some instructions (like single-operand `imul`) only operate on fixed registers. However, these instructions are rare and most of them are obsolete, rendering this choice much less important in practice.

Another issue that depending on your calling convention, some registers must be preserved when returning, so before using them for your own purpose, you have to save their value. If you only need a few registers in your function, it is useful to avoid such registers so you can get rid of the corresponding pushes and pops.

Comment: Interesting! Gotta read about register renaming. Come to think of it, just one calculation register would make for terrible performance.

Comment: @Olumide Older processors had one physical register for each logical register. This is reasonably fast, but the processor has to wait for each instruction to finish before another instruction can be dispatched. This is avoided with register renaming, so instructions can be dispatched even when the previous instruction hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Register renaming only became important when out-of-order execution was introduced. Before that, everything was serialized, so it didn't really help to have more physical registers than exposed by the ISA. One calculation register doesn't necessarily make for "terrible" performance. I mean, I guess it does in modern terms, but the 6502 was a darn powerful processor in its day. Anyway, the direct answer to the question is no; all 7 x86 registers today are equivalent, general-purpose registers. You only use a specific one if an instruction forces you to do so. (Those are hardly obsolete though!)